# Installing java 6 appears to have depdency on multiarch-support

Tags: java, ubuntu, dependencies

I'm trying to install java 6 on Linux (Ubuntu) and I'm running into circular dependencies with the deb packages.

I have downloaded the following packages from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-6/  :

```
openjdk-6-jre-lib_6b41-1.13.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb
openjdk-6-dbg_6b41-1.13.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_arm64.deb
openjdk-6-demo_6b41-1.13.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_arm64.deb
openjdk-6-jdk_6b41-1.13.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_arm64.deb
openjdk-6-jre_6b41-1.13.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_arm64.deb
openjdk-6-jre-headless_6b41-1.13.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_arm64.deb
```

I start by installing (using GDebi package installer) openjdk-6-jre-lib which claims it has a dependency on openjdk-6-jre-headless but when I try to install that it has a reverse dependency on openjdk-6-jre-lib.

However when I try this from the command line (using dpkg -i) I get different errors.

```
E: openjdk-6-jre-lib: depends-on-obsolete-package Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b27)
W: openjdk-6-jre-lib: breakout-link usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/jre/lib/mime.types -> etc/mime.types
N: 0 hints overridden; 1 unused override

  openjdk-6-jre-headless pre-depends on multiarch-support
  multiarch-support is not installed.
```

What multiarch do I need when I'm installing all arm64 packages.?  What other arch do I need?

There doesn't appear to be a multiarch-support package available!

Comment: May I ask why you even want to install that old, unsupported java version? Why not at least the currently still supported Java 1.8 or even one of the newers like Java 11 or Java 17?

Comment: `multiarch-support` looks like a "dummy package" / a bug? : Text files only = `/usr/share/doc/multiarch-support/{ changelog.Debian.gz,  changelog.gz,  copyright }`, where "changelog.Debian" is for `glibc`. .... Example http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20190501T215844Z/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.28-10_arm64.deb ... → `Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-2)`

Comment: @ThomasKläger The application requires java 6 and I have tested several other java versions including 1.8 and the GUI components are not compatible and do not load.